# Excel find and replace substring in a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
String is "TABLE1[ROW1]"
```

Using Find and Replace the substring "TABLE1" should be replaced such that [ROW1] is retained after replacement.

Final String after replacement

```
INDIRECT(D1&"[ROW1]")
```

I am having trouble with inserting ") After [ROW1].

I have seen some samples for retaining using "^&", but no solution to this problem.

Kindly Help. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please include a formula that you use? Is adding ")" to the end only problem that you have: btw, it should be done simply by & ")". Rgds,

Comment: =MIN(IF(TABLE1[ROW1])=S1,TABLE1[ROW2]))
To
=MIN(IF(INDIRECT(D96&"[ROW1]")=S1,INDIRECT(D96&"[ROW2]")))

D96 is the cell with value TABLE1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having cell A1 containing the string `TABLE1[ROW1]`, using Excel worksheet function SUBSTITUTE as following: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"TABLE1", "")`, then adding the word "**INDIRECT(D1&**" resulting in the cell A2 formula:

`="INDIRECT(D1&" & """"  & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"TABLE1", "") & """" & ")"`,

transforming the original string **TABLE1[ROW1]** into the string: **INDIRECT(D1&"[ROW1]")** as per your requirement.

Hope this will help. Rgds